Setting button text from variable causes "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'LocalizedStringKey'"
This is a simple question, but I can't figure it out.
I have a custom button with label: Text() in SwiftUI:
The button is defined like this:
public struct KlikButtonOutline: View {
    let title: LocalizedStringKey
    let disabled: Bool
    let action: () -> Void

    public var body: some View {
        Button() {
            action()
        } label: {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}

This works fine and shows a button with "Sign out" text.
KlikButtonOutline("Sign out") {...}
I want to extract my texts to a separate file doing it like this:
struct ProfileViewLabels {
    static let SignInButtonText = "Sign in"
    static let SignOutButtonText: String = "Sign out"
}

Using it looks like this:
KlikButtonOutline(ProfileViewLabels.SignOutText) {...}
This causes an error:
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'LocalizedStringKey'
I do realice the the input is declared a localizable string, but why is "Some text" a localizable string and static let text = "Some text" not?

have you tried using Button(ProfileViewLabels.SignOutButtonText) {...}

The initialiser of KlikButtonOutline takes a LocalizedStringKey, but ProfileViewLabels.SignOutText is a String.
If you instead pass in a string literal like "Some Text", the string literal can be converted to a LocalizedStringKey, because LocalizedStringKey conforms to ExpressibleByStringLiteral. Only string literals can be converted this way.
If you want to the string constants to be localized, change their type to LocalizedStringKey, not String.
struct ProfileViewLabels {
    // Again, the string literals here are converted to LocalizedStringKey
    static let SignInButtonText: LocalizedStringKey = "Sign in"
    static let SignOutButtonText: LocalizedStringKey = "Sign out"
}

If you want your button to also accept verbatim text (that are not localized) as the title. See this post.
Related Post
